# How to set enum to range of number in typeorm

Tags: enums, nestjs, typeorm

I want to create an enum with a range of numbers from 1 to 200.

There are too many to list all of them one by one, so I want to use a function like `range`.

```js
export enum NumberData {
  // ???
}
```

In the code above `???`,
Please tell me what code to put inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, is not possible. Because enums in TypeScript translates to function in javascript (not arrays). You can't automatically fill fields inside a function. You can fill only arrays

```
enum NumberData {
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2
}
// translates to =>
"use strict";
var NumberData;
(function (NumberData) {
    NumberData[NumberData["ONE"] = 1] = "ONE";
    NumberData[NumberData["TWO"] = 2] = "TWO";
})(NumberData || (NumberData = {}));
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I'll try to find another way.